# Blogspot Latex equation

Tags: latex, blogger, mathjax

I want to write Latex equation in Blogspot so I have chosen a dynamic template and pasted the `HTML code` after the `<head>` tag.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  // <![CDATA[   
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
                      displayMath: [['\\[','\\]'], ['$$','$$']]}});   
  blogger.ui().viewType_.prototype.onRenderComplete=function(){MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub])};   
  // ]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

[image]
After inserting some input I am not getting the Latex output. I have used another method but it is not working. How to fix it explicitly? 
[image]

Comment: It seems like the symbols were encoded, as the code you pasted doesn't match that of what you have in your web header. `'` > `&quot;`...

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 4):

Forget the &quot and stuff. The latex output is not appearing in the Preview mode but **it will appear properly when you publish that post**.

**Reason**: the preview url is an https url and looks something like https://blogname.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=fsdbkdsbkjsdfnkjsdnf&postId=32798437243279&type=POST. Since the page is https your browser tries to load the script http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js also as https which generates a certificate error.

Since the viewers of your blog will never open it in https they won't ever face this problem. **If you want to see the preview with correct latex output just click on Preview button. When the page loads replace https with http in the url and Bingo!!**

Comment: "click on Preview button. When the page loads replace https with http in the url"  That's it! It works! +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing with the blogger template, my solution is to use a plugin http://markdown-here.com/

Just write your equation like $sum_2^n{\pi}$

Note that there's no space between dollar sign and the equation.

Alternatively, another online markdown tool is https://stackedit.io/ . It's free and provides a direct output to Blogger. The pitfall is what you write is cached in the browser. When you have 10+ documents in the caches, there's a severe time lag in display.

For people who is not familiar with Latex equation, here is a reference: http://www.hostmath.com/

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with the very same issue, wondering for days why the LaTeX equation was not being rendered properly after adding the CDN. Unable to find a descriptive answer, I decided to provide one for people like myself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

Please note that your code is not incorrect. The text editor of Blogger adds HTML on top of your input, which is why it is not rendered properly. You need to write the LaTeX equation in HTML Mode (select HTML view from the top-left header) of your Blogger post..